# How to wrap constructor function in IIFE & place instance on Window object?

Tags: javascript, constructor, window, iife

I want a file to attach a property to the `Window` object.  This is the code I currently have

```
function Binary() {
    var obj = function(msg){ console.log(msg + this.binaryString ) };
    obj.binaryString = ''

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'zero', {
        get: function() {
            obj.binaryString += '0';
            return obj;
        }
    });

    ....

    return obj;
};

var binary = new Binary();
```

I want to wrap this whole thing in an IIFE and place the `binary` instance as a property on the `Window` object (this will be a library and I don't want variable names to conflict).  I have tried a couple of different times and get a `max callstack error`  How would I do this correctly?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, I've just wrapped it in an IIFE and changed `var binary = new Binary();` to `window.binary = new Binary();` and it all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do it this way:

```
(function(){ /*Put code here.*/; window.binary = result; })()
```

Or this way with `return`:

```js
'use strict';
window.binary = (function() {

  var obj = function(msg){ console.log(msg + this.binaryString ) };
  obj.binaryString = ''
  
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'zero', {
    get: function() {
      obj.binaryString += '0';
      return obj;
    }
  });
  // ...
  return obj;

})();
console.log('1', window.binary);
console.log('2', binary);

/*
In modern JavaScript you may use `{...Code here...}` + `let`/`const`
as a scope, but it doesn't work for `var`s!
*/
'use strict'; // Don't forget strict mode!
{
  const foo = 42;
  let choo = 'Choo choo!';
  var goo = 55; // Leaks!

  function poo() { console.log('POO!'); }

  window.bar = 'baz';
}
console.log('foo', window.foo);   // undefined
console.log('choo', window.choo); // undefined
console.log('goo', window.goo);   // DEFINED!
console.log('poo', window.poo);   // undefined
console.log('bar', window.bar);   // DEFINED!
```

Comment: In this particular example, the IIFE does nothing since everything is contained inside your Binary() function.

Comment: This way you don't pollute global namespace, do you?

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov This now works if I call `Window.binary.zero()` but now if I call `binary.zero()` binary is undefined.  How can I simply just call `binary.zero()` when `binary` is placed on the `Window` obj?  I basically want it to function like jQuery does

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov That was the problem, I put it on `Window` instead of `window`, it works now, thank you!